# Trying to delete a file after using said file, using visual basic

Tags: vb.net, pdf, ioexception

I am developing a program that creates a PDF file from the screenshot of the program window. Here is the layout/UI for my program: [image]

Essentially for my program, I am taking a screenshot of the UI you see above, saving that as a Jpg file, and then turning that Jpg file into a PDF.

Once the program successfully converts the Jpg into a PDF, I want the program to delete the Jpg, leaving the PDF file behind. The **issue** arises with this `IOexception` error coming up from the `2) Create PDF` button click event:

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Aliza\OneDrive\Desktop\test14\notebook_3412312.jpg' because it is being used by another process.'

I should note that the program successfully makes the PDF like I want to, but I just want the program to delete the Jpeg file after it has created a PDF out of that Jpg file.

Here is my code from the `2) Create PDF` event:

```
    Dim filename As String
    Dim collectionPeriod As String
    Dim fileLocation As String
    filename = CompNam.Text
    If filename = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Enter name of your file")
        End
    End If
    collectionPeriod = collectPeriod.Text
    If collectionPeriod = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Enter name of your collection period")
        End
    End If

    fileLocation = folderBrowseBox.Text

    GetFormImage(True).Save(fileLocation & "\" & RemoveWhitespace(filename) & "_" & RemoveWhitespace(collectionPeriod) & ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)

    ' Create new pdf document and page
    Dim doc As New PdfDocument()
    Dim oPage As New PdfPage()

    ' Add the page to the pdf document and add the captured image to it
    doc.Pages.Add(oPage)
    Dim img As XImage = XImage.FromFile(fileLocation & "\" & RemoveWhitespace(filename) & "_" & RemoveWhitespace(collectionPeriod) & ".jpg")

    'Create XImage object from file.
    Using xImg = PdfSharp.Drawing.XImage.FromFile(fileLocation & "\" & RemoveWhitespace(filename) & "_" & RemoveWhitespace(collectionPeriod) & ".jpg")
        'Resize page Width and Height to fit image size.
        oPage.Width = xImg.PixelWidth * 72 / xImg.HorizontalResolution
        oPage.Height = xImg.PixelHeight * 72 / xImg.HorizontalResolution

        'Draw current image file to page.
        Dim xgr = PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics.FromPdfPage(oPage)
        xgr.DrawImage(xImg, 0, 0, oPage.Width, oPage.Height)
    End Using

    System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance)

    doc.Save(fileLocation & "\" & RemoveWhitespace(filename) & "_" & RemoveWhitespace(collectionPeriod) & ".pdf")

    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(fileLocation & "\" & RemoveWhitespace(filename) & "_" & RemoveWhitespace(collectionPeriod) & ".jpg")
    img.Dispose()
```

The error occurs from the 2nd to last line of code you see from above (starts with `My.Computer.FileSystem...`). Again, Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Edit: @ jmcilhinney Here is the code I tried to add based off your recommendation:

```
    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = fileLocation & "\" & RemoveWhitespace(filename) & "_" & RemoveWhitespace(collectionPeriod) & ".jpg"

    Using img As XImage = XImage.FromFile(filePath)
        img.Dispose()
    End Using

    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(filePath)
```

I know you said not to put a `Dispose()` call in the `Using` statement, but I'm having a hard time of what it exactly to put in between that `Using` statement. Again, thank you for being really patient with me when it comes to helping me.

Comment: Firstly, don't build the same file path multiple times. Build the path once, using `Path.Combine` or `My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath` to combine multiple partial paths. You can then use `Path.ChangeExtension` to create another file path with just the extension changed.

Comment: As for the issue, it seems to be that you need to dispose the `Image` object before trying to delete the file. If you created the `Image` object by calling `Image.FromFile` or `New Bitmap` then that will lock the file until the object is disposed.

Comment: Read the comment I made on my answer again and, this time, do what I actually said. I was very specific about the instructions and you have just blundered in and done a vague approximation of what I said. I shouldn't need to repeat myself when what I said was written down and still available to you to read as many times as you need to. Read what I wrote. Do what I wrote. That is all. The code you posted even has a `Using` block in it already so it's not like you shouldn't already know how to use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution to this problem was quite simple. After talking through it with a friend, all we had to do was to create a `TempPath` when we declare our `filePath` variable:

```
    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath & RemoveWhitespace(filename) & "_" & RemoveWhitespace(collectionPeriod) & ".jpg"
```

The problem before was that we were saving our Jpeg file using the text from our `fileLocation` variable, which kept on bringing up that "process being used by another process" error.

The use of a `Using` block was proved to be unnecessary. Quite on the contrary, it actually brought about more harm than good. Here is the new, refined code:

```
    fileLocation = folderBrowseBox.Text

    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath & RemoveWhitespace(filename) & "_" & RemoveWhitespace(collectionPeriod) & ".jpg"

    GetFormImage(True).Save(filePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg)

    ' Create new pdf document and page
    Dim doc As New PdfDocument()
    Dim oPage As New PdfPage()

    ' Add the page to the pdf document and add the captured image to it
    doc.Pages.Add(oPage)

    'Create XImage object from file.
    Dim xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(oPage)
    Dim xImg = XImage.FromFile(filePath)

    oPage.Width = xImg.PixelWidth * 72 / xImg.HorizontalResolution
    oPage.Height = xImg.PixelHeight * 72 / xImg.HorizontalResolution

    xgr.DrawImage(xImg, 0, 0, oPage.Width, oPage.Height)

    System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance)

    doc.Save(fileLocation & "\" & RemoveWhitespace(filename) & "_" & RemoveWhitespace(collectionPeriod) & ".pdf")

    doc.Close()

    xImg.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like these two lines should be the other way around:

```vb
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(fileLocation & "\" & RemoveWhitespace(filename) & "_" & RemoveWhitespace(collectionPeriod) & ".jpg")

img.Dispose()
```

If `img` is an `Image` object created from the file you're trying to delete using either `Image.FromFile` or `New Bitmap` then the file is locked until the `Image` object is disposed. Ideally, you would create the `Image` using a `Using` statement and then delete the file outside the block, e.g.

```vb
Dim filePath = "file path here"

Using img = Image.FromFile(filePath)
    'Use img here.
End Using

File.Delete(filePath)
```

Comment: I'll add the first half of my code back into my main post, primarily the part with how I declared `img` object. I don't really understand what to do just based off your post. But, I'll add the first half of my code back into my original post.

Comment: To be honest, from the `Create new pdf document and page` comment all the way down to the end of my code you see above, I got that code from another Stack Overflow Q & A board on how to make my PDF. So I don't exactly know how to make changes to my code without disrupting the other parts of the code, based off your answer

Comment: @alkhanate458, that's why you should take the time to understand what code you get from elsewhere is doing rather than just copying and pasting blindly. Regardless, you do basically exactly what I showed in my code. Create `XImage` object with a `Using` statement instead of a `Dim` statement, the `End Using` statement would replace the `Dispose` call and then you move the `DeleteFile` call outside that block.

Comment: I made an edit above that tried to add in your recommendation from ur code

Comment: What do you mean by the line of code in your answer `'Use img here`? Are you talking about the code used to create the PDF by using the `XImage` object? More so, in my own words (so you can point out if there are any discrepancies in my thought-process), what we are doing is that we are declaring `img` with a `Using` statement, and we set it as an `XImage` object from the `filePath`, defining the latter as a string. After we create that instance of `img` (by ending it with a `End Using` statement), we can then delete the jpg file by placing `FileDelete` outside our `Using` block of code. Yes?

Comment: It's a comment. It means exactly what it says. `img` is a variable and you use it exactly where I put a comment telling you to use it. As I pointed out, you already have a `Using` block in the code you posted originally so you SHOULD already know how a `using` block works because, if you didn't, you should have researched it in your effort to understand that code.

Comment: *"After we create that instance of img"*. You're not creating an instance of `img`. `img` is a variable, not a type. You're declaring the `img` variable, creating an instance of the `XImage` type and assigning it to that variable. The object works like any other object and the variable works like any other variable. The point of the `Using` block, as you should have discovered for yourself, is to dispose the object automatically at the end of the block. The variable can only be used inside the block, just like any other variable can only be used inside the block it's declared in.

Comment: I was able to get the program working, but it wasn't through your way/method. Regardless, I appreciate your patience in trying to assist me with this problem

Comment: @alkhanate458, you should post your own answer showing your solution. It might help someone else in future and, if the solution is suboptimal, we can let you know what's wrong with it so you can improve it.